# ORA-19112: error raised during evaluation while converting comma separated strings to rows using XMLTABLE

Tags: java, sql, oracle, xmltable

I am trying to split comma separated strings into rows using XMLTABLE function in oracle.
e.g.

```
 WITH MYTABLE AS
  (SELECT '"AB","PQ","XY"' TEXT FROM DUAL
  )
SELECT REPLACE((column_value).GETSTRINGVAL(),'"','') "OPTION_TEXT"
FROM MYTABLE,
  XMLTABLE(TEXT);
```

above query works fine. But when string with & is passed, it throws exception as

*java.sql.SQLException: ORA-19112: error raised during evaluation:*

```
 WITH MYTABLE AS
  (SELECT '"AB","P & Q","XY"' TEXT FROM DUAL
  )
SELECT REPLACE((column_value).GETSTRINGVAL(),'"','') "OPTION_TEXT"
FROM MYTABLE,
  XMLTABLE(TEXT);
```

Note that this query is being executed from java through prepared statement.

Comment: Yeah, but what has it got to do with Java?

Comment: i am specifying it because i don't want you to consider options like SET define OFF;
SET ESCAPE OFF;
SET SCAN OFF; while giving answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the evaluation of the XQuery expression.

You could [**split the comma delimited string into rows**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2014/12/02/split-comma-delimited-string-into-rows-in-oracle/) using **REGEXP_SUBSTR**.

Check out this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7/6696)

**Working demo:**

```
SQL> WITH mytable AS
  2    (SELECT '"AB","P & Q","XY"' TEXT FROM DUAL
  3    )
  4  SELECT trim(regexp_substr(TEXT, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) TEXT
  5  FROM mytable
  6    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(TEXT, ',')+1;

TEXT
-----------------
"AB"
"P & Q"
"XY"
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is with [special characters](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97337_01/ias102_otn/buslog.102/bc4j/obcCustomXml.htm) inside XML.

Quick (probably dirty) workaround is to use `REPLACE` to replace special chars:

```
WITH MYTABLE AS
  (SELECT '"AB","P  & Q","XY"' TEXT FROM DUAL
  )
SELECT REPLACE(extractValue(column_value,'/text()'),'"','') "OPTION_TEXT"
FROM MYTABLE,
  XMLTABLE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(TEXT, '&', '&#38;'), '<', '&lt;'), '>', '&gt;'));
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7/6694/0)**</kbd>